# Ag Grid Cell Renderer

Tags: angular, grid

I am using singe Ag Grid Cell Renderer, in different screens. Now i want to add different styles on on one of the screen for cell renderer value based on condition. How to apply styles dynamically in such case?

Comment: You want to render value in different style ?

Comment: @upinder kumar :  yes, specially i want to change the color of text in renderer.

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**try this :**

```
columns= [
{

 headerName: 'Employee'
 field : 'emp'
 colId : 'emp'

},
{

 headerName: 'Role'
 field : 'role'
 colId : 'role'

}
]
```

**in Cell Renderer Component**

```
export class CellRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  public params: any;

  constructor() {}

  agInit(params) {

   this.params = params;

  }

}
```

**in HTML file**

```
<div>
<span class="customClass" *ngIf="params.colDef.colId === 'emp'">{{params.data}}</span>
<span class="customClassforRole" *ngIf="params.colDef.colId === 'role'">{{params.data}}</span>
</div>
```

For Reference : [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/)

Comment: this will apply styles for different columns, i want to apply it on same column name but on diff screen. i am using single cell renderer for all screen. can i add any property on column defination for styles. except cellStyle and cell Class , that is not working in this case, i have already used that.

Comment: add same colId for that column

Comment: params.colDef.colId this is giving error colId does not exist.